# K3b CD ripping - can't change LAME settings

Tags: mp3, cd-ripping, k3b, lame

I'm trying to rip a CD to mp3 with VBR setting V0. In an earlier version of K3b, you could configure the LAME command string. But in version 19.12.3, that has been replaced with a screen in the LAME configuration settings with entries for maximum, average, and minimum bitrates:

[image: Variable bit rate config screen in K3b]

However, no matter what I specify here (and I do have Variable Bitrate selected), the media properties of the ripped mp3 file show:

**Encoding settings**  -m j -V 4 -q 0 -lowpass 17.5 --vbr-new -b -32

And the bitrate is around 160. So it's always ripping at V4, but I want V0. I've tried changing the minimum and average bitrate entries, but to no avail. How can I get K3b to rip at V0?

(Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the command line settings for LAME can be achieved under a modern version version of K3b as follows:

After installing LAME:

```
sudo apt-get install lame
```

go to the appropriate K3b menu:

```
Settings --> Configure K3b --> Plugins
```

From here select 'K3b External Audio Encoder' and select the 'Configure' option (at the right where there is a 'Configure' and an 'About' option). Now either *add* or *modify* an MP3 encoder to look something like the following:

[image]

And then you should be right to go! The settings shown here are actually the defaults from my Slackware system but `-V 0` or perhaps better: `--preset extreme` can easily be substituted.

Another option is to simply add *the same options* in `$HOME/.config/k3brc` where they will look something like the following (again as seen on my own system):

```
[K3bExternalEncoderPlugin]
command_Flac=Flac,flac,flac -V -o %f --force-raw-format --endian=little --channels=2 --sample-rate=44100 --sign=signed --bps=16 -T ARTIST=%a -T TITLE=%t -T TRACKNUMBER=%n -T DATE=%y -T ALBUM=%m -
command_Mp3 (Lame)=Mp3 (Lame),mp3,lame -r --bitwidth 16 --little-endian -s 44.1 -h --tt %t --ta %a --tl %m --ty %y --tc %c --tn %n - %f
commands=Flac,Mp3 (Lame)
```

And then all that is required is to experiment with your LAME options until you find the best ones for your playback equipment and your listening tastes :).